# Config.groovy in Grails: grails.views.default.codec - why base64?

Tags: grails

The Config.groovy setting `grails.views.default.codec` specifies the default codec used to encode data with `${...}`.

This config setting can take any of the values `none`, `html` and `base64`.

I understand the reason to why one would set them to `none` (no filtering required) or `html` (to avoid XSS-attacks), but why would anyone like to set it to base64-encoding?

Please provide a specific use-case when it would be appropriate to set it to `base64`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is most probably no real use case for this. It should just illustrate that you can use any codec (bundled or your own) as the default codec for views.

Comment: Hi Siegfried! Thanks for your excellent Grails answers! Have you seen this bounty question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/631490/grails-urlmappings-with-url-pattern-ending-with) - seems like a hard question to answer, but maybe you know how to fix it?